# Rails 4 - Javascript - trouble with .not()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Can someone tell me what is wrong in this Javascript ?

It's supposed to show an alert "already opened" if there's plus (or) 2 PP div with a class "open".

```
if ($('PP').not('.closed')>=2) {
                  window.alert('already opened');

                 }
```

Comment: remove that line with thanks. Wait for the right answer and upvote and accept it instead. BTW did you try printing $('PP') or $('PP').not('.closed') in the console? I guess you have to take LENGTH of this part to compare. I'm not a JS guy though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jquery's `not` function will return a jquery object, not an integer.

I can't validate if the rest of your logic is working but if you want to get the number of DOM elements that matches your jquery element, you should do it using the `length` value:

```
if ($('PP').not('.closed').length>=2) {
  window.alert('already opened');
}
```